# How to get file path VS project on Ubuntu?

Tags: c

I have a `C` project. I am working in VisualStudio on Ubuntu.

I need to read from a file.

I have this method:

```
        fp = fopen("path_to_file", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nERROR : file open failed\n");
            return 0;
        }
        while (fgets(buffer, MAX_NAME_LENGTH, (FILE *)fp))
        {
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        if (line)
            free(line);
```

My file is located at the root of my project, so my question is - is there a way set way to file like this `${project_root}/my_tmp.txt`?

This way `${project_root}` will be like a general value.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to utilize the *Tasks* feature of VSCode and pass the project root path to your compiler as a preprocessor macro using the `-D` option, after which you could use it in your sourcecode.

An example (refer [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) for the complete documentation regarding Tasks) `tasks.json` file could look like this. Note the `-D` argument in the `args` array.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "default build option",
      "command": "/usr/bin/cc",
      "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}", "-DPROJECT_ROOT=\"${project_root}\""],
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, in your C source, you could utilize the `PROJECT_ROOT` macro to construct the filename to open:

```
fp = fopen(PROJECT_ROOT "/path_to_file", "r");
```